# why in python giving to str func a unicode string will throw an exception?

Tags: python, unicode, string

for example the following:
str(u'לשום')
will throw an error.
how can i prevent these?

Comment: It works fine on my Python 2.6.5. Which version are you running this on?

Comment: it raises an error? What does the error say?

Comment: works fine in python2.4+ so what version of python are you using? show us some real code

Comment: It raises a Syntax Error on Python 3 because the `u` prefix is no longer valid (because all strings are Unicode anyway).

Answer (score 7):

Calling `str()` on a `unicode` is the same as calling `.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())` on it. If the `unicode` contains characters that can't be encoded in the default encoding then it will throw a `UnicodeEncodeError`. The fix is to explicitly encode the `unicode` in a useful encoding, such as `'utf-8'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Python 3, the `u''` notation is a syntax error. Is this your problem? Because in Python <3, your code is absolutely correct, and since 'test' is plain ASCII there are no decoding issues.